# RTK-Query conditional typing of BaseQueryFn

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In RTK, I'm using a custom `baseQuery` to wrap axios, following the general guidance [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries).  However, I can't seem to figure out a way to use conditional typing for the `BaseQueryArg` type.  For example, I'd like to be able to have my baseQuery function take in the following argument object:

```
{
  url: string
  method: "GET" | "PUT" | "POST" | "DELETE"
  body: any
}
```

But, rather than have `body` be `any`, or even a stricter union, I'd like to have it vary depend on the type of `method`.  So, for example, if this was a simple function I would type it like so:

```
function myBaseQueryFunction<T extends "GET"|"POST">(args: {
  url: string
  method: T
  body: T extends "POST" ? {someBodyData: string} : null
}){
  // do the query
}
```

However, I can't seem to find any way to use that kind of typing for the function I pass to `baseQuery` and have it properly restrict the return types of of my `query` endpoints.  Even if I don't use the `BaseQueryFn` utility type and, instead, manually type a function like the one above and then pass it to `baseQuery`, I still don't get the restriction on `query`'s return that I want.

Is there anyway to do this kind of conditional typing of `baseQuery`?

### Update

Per the accepted answer below, the simplest way to handle this is with a discriminated union on method, e.g.:

```
type BaseQueryDiscriminatedArg = 
  | {
      url: string
      method: "POST"
      body: {someBodyData: string}
     }
  | {
      url: string
      method: "GET"
      body?: null
     }
```

and then your `BaseQueryFn` type is just `BaseQueryFn<BaseQueryDiscriminatedArg>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this should be possible by using a discriminated union type for the argument, using `method` as the discriminator. Overloads or generics won't work, since TS cannot map correctly over those, hence the wrong resulting types.

If you have more problems with that, a chat might help more. Just stop by in the Redux channel on Reactiflux

Comment: a discriminated union works here.  thanks.  i actually have a more complicated use case where it's not ideal, but i will ask a different question or go on chat.